# Broken Link on Context Right Click - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

In my project I am showing information of horse track's.
On click of track Name,I am redirecting user to track information using backbone.js.
If user right-click on that link and open it in another window then link is getting broken

1. Backbone router.js - 
   Here i am adding below line in history so before every url "race-entries" will get added.

   ```
   Backbone.history.start({ pushState : true, root : "/race-entries/"});
   ```
2. Backbone view .js -

   ```
   <a class="trackView" href="/entries/tracks/<%=trackId %>/country/<%=country %>/date/<%= date %>">View</a>
   ```

So when i click on anchor tag url get redirected to entries Component of php , and in backbone it go to entries router but url will be replaced with

```
 /race-entries/tracks/MNR/country/USA/date/20170104
(/race-entries/ is root in backbone route.)
```

and in this way it works correctly.
but if we open it into other tab , backbone router context is over so it opens 
in other tab and it shows 404 page.

```
        /entries/tracks/MNR/country/USA/date/20170104
```

If i replace entries with rae-entries in code then after opening link in other tab /race-entries/ is getting repeated.

```
   / race-entries/race-entries/tracks/MNR/country/USA/date/20170104
```

Comment: Why do you need t oset root for history? Try removing the root : "/race-entries/"

Comment: Actually my client want 'race-entries' at the start og url

Comment: then in that case you will have to configure your backend. What technology are you using on your backend?

Comment: I am using php , and now thinking to change controllers name , routes in php. So it will be better thing

Comment: you can simply change the route in PHP if you are using any MVC framework. prefix /race-entries/ to every route.

Comment: I am using yii framework.Currently my controllers name is entries ,result and liveOdd. and wanted to change it to race-entries , race-results and so on

Comment: Sorry I haven't used yii framework. But I had a look at it and I guess simply adding /race-entries/ at start of your routes should do